# Left_join with Df1 and a list of equal dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe, left-join

I have an issue with joining 4 data frames. I work with remote access in a secured environment, so unfortunately I'm not able to provide you with screenshots of my R session and the codes.

I have R version 3.4.1
and package tidyverse

Df1 - One dataframe has 280000 rows and 20 variables, this is my main dataset and it contains diagnoses data, hospital departments and locations data.

HA1, HA2, HA3 - The other 3 datasets each have between 23 and 25 million rows and 7 variables, the variables are equal in all 3 datasets. The datasets contain data about healthcare activities of 3 seperate years.

I want to join these datasets using the variable "A" with a left_join. As in, only keeping the healthcare activities in HA1-3 that have a matching diagnosis/hospital in Df1.

I tried this as a test with HA1:

```
test = left_join(Df1, HA1, by= "A")
```

This worked fine.
but after I tried to add HA2 and HA3 to the dataset it added new variables instead of filling in the NAs of the already added variables of HA1. (var.x, var.y)

```
test2 = left_join (test, HA2, by= "A") 

test3 = left_join (test2, HA3, by= "A")
```

After this I tried an rbind on the HA datasets but these are too large and I get an error: "cannot allocate vector of size..".

So I tried the purrr package with the reduce function, but I had the same issue

```
list(Df1, HA1, HA2, HA3) %>% reduce(left_join, by = "A")
```

The dataset that I am trying to make has the 20 variables of Df 1 and the 7 variables of HA1-3. I tried to add the 7 variables of the HA datasets once to Df1, and add all matches of HA1-3 in the same columns.

Hopefully you're able to help me with this problem without the R screenshots.

Comment: try it with data.table package. data.frame operations creates another copy of it sometime and it can consume too much available system RAM. instead of left_join use merge and instead of reduce/rbind use rbindlist. Suggesting this as your datasets seems big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

left_join will always add new columns, rather than fill in an existing one. A simple solution for this is to use `coalesce` to combine the three new columns into one. Here's an example with dummy data and three dataframes:

```
d<-data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:5])
e<-data.frame(A=LETTERS[1:3],b=1:3)
f<-data.frame(A=LETTERS[4:5],b=4:5)
left_join(d,e,by="A") %>% left_join(f,by="A") %>%
mutate(newb=coalesce(b.x,b.y))

  A b.x b.y newb
1 A   1  NA    1
2 B   2  NA    2
3 C   3  NA    3
4 D  NA   4    4
5 E  NA   5    5
```

Comment: +10, Could use `purrr::reduce(list(d, e, f), ~left_join(.x, .y, by = "A"))` to perform joining in order to scale it better to more `data.frame`s

Comment: Absolutely right, @zack. Didn't bother with it since OP seemed to only have the four, and I didn't want to complicate the answer.